# Bundle install failed for mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, mysql2

I updated my local machine mysql from 5.7 to 8 and after installing it couldn't install DB Adapter `mysql2` gem via `bundle install` command.

However, i am able to install it with the following command.

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.5' -- --with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.3/lib --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.3 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.3/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@8.3/include --with-ldflags="-L$(brew --prefix zstd)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib" --with-cppflags="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include"
```

it installs successfully

```
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.5.5
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.5.5
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when tried running tests it says

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (= 0.5.5)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

so i try bundle install and it fails with

```
38 warnings generated.
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete
ld: library 'zstd' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1
```

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.5'` succeeds before bundling.

Background: After updating when i tried running the test, it was searching for some path of mysql@5.7 inside `/vendor/mysql2-0.5.5/` directory so i tried uninstalling this gem but after that it couldn't install again.

Ruby version: 2.5.8

Rails version: 2.318 (I know its really old :( )

Comment: According to the mysql2 read me (https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/tree/master) you need to install mysql2 0.2.x to work with Rails / Active Record 2.3 - 3.0.

Comment: `gem install` doesn't update your `Gemfile` (which is what `bundler` and Rails itself are looking at). Learn more about how to pin a gem to a specific version in your `Gemfile` here: https://bundler.io/guides/gemfile.html

Comment: my gem file already has mysql2 as the dependency 

`gem 'mysql2', '0.5.5' `

Any hints how to tell bundler and Rails that this gem is already installed through `gem install`